# scikit-learn decision tree important features order and max-depth choice relation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Why does the order of feature importances change according to the max depth choice in the decision tree classifier?

I used the synthetic data, but I didn't share the code because it is unnecessary and long. I just wonder the logic behind that when I change the maximum depth, why does the order of important features change.

```
dec_tree_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=23, criterion="entropy")   
dec_tree_clf.fit(X_data, y_data)
```

---

```
features    importance  
    z   0.267464  
    n   0.124694  
    y   0.094134  
    c   0.090750  
    i   0.084806
```

```
dec_tree_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=23, criterion="entropy")   
dec_tree_clf.fit(X_data, y_data)
```

```
features    importance  
    z   0.350545  
    n   0.163426  
    c   0.118939    
    i   0.111149  
    b   0.106650
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/feature-importance-measures-for-tree-models-part-i-47f187c1a2c3)  you can see that the Gini importance "*counts the times a feature is used to split a node, weighted by the number of samples it splits*".

If you have a feature which splits a lot in a large tree it will naturally have fewer splits in a short tree, thus might change the Gini importance (aka the *Feature Importance* [(It is the same)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.feature_importances_)). Also the splits might be different in a tree with `depth=3` compared to a tree with `depth=4`which then also changes the Gini importance.